# Laravel/Blade -- is there a way to escape all output except formatting-type tags?

Tags: php, html, laravel, markdown, laravel-blade

I'm learning Laravel coming from a javascript background, so I'm not super familiar with PHP. I'm trying to make an app that has a textarea input, and displays the input formatted with markdown. I'm using [Parsedown](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown) to parse the markdown into HTML, and then in my blade template, I use:

```
{!! $post->body !!}
```

to display it. It comes out being formatted with the HTML, but of course this also runs the risk of `<script>` tags, etc, being unescaped as well.

Is there an easy way to make sure only things like `<p>`, `<ul>`, `<em>`, and other things created by markdown are unescaped?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Laravel does not provide out-of-the box solution for that. When you might be interested in when it comes to cleaning potentially suspicious input, take a look at the **[HTML Purifier for Laravel](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier)**.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your own custom tag to the blade engine, Will provide link when I get home. As second solution you could create an extension. [Blade extension (laravel docs)](http://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#extending-blade)